# In a TreeView in WPF, is there a way to get the index of the child node that is selected and the index of the parent node of that selected child item

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, treeview

I am trying to populate a treeview using a three-level object.

Input for the treeview is ObservableCollection(GroupClass) where GroupClass contains a property called devices = ObservableCollection(DeviceDetails).

When I click on a DeviceDetails object in the UI, I would like to get the index of DeviceDetails item and the index of the GroupClass object it belongs to.

I have successfully populated the treeview using the collection of the GroupClass using a hierarchical template and data template.

I have looked at how to get the details of the selected item in a treeview, but most of the solution used TreeViewItem.Selected trigger.

In my case, as I am using a hierarchical template and data template I don't have any TreeView Item defined in my XAML.

Group Class:

```
public class GroupClass
{
    public GroupClass()
    {
        this.devices = new ObservableCollection<DeviceDetails>();
    }

    public string groupName { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<DeviceDetails> devices { get; set; }
}

public class DeviceDetails
{
    public DeviceDetails()
    {
        this.status = "Online";
        this.ipAddress = "192.168.1.1";
        this.dateAccessed = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public string deviceName { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public DateTime dateAccessed { get; set; }
    public string ipAddress { get; set; }
}
```

XAML code for populating TreeView:

```
<Grid x:Name="ListPage" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,80,0,0" >
    <TreeView x:Name="HostTreeView" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:GroupClass}" ItemsSource="{Binding devices}">
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Name="HeaderPanel5">
                    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" >
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding groupName}" />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DeviceDetails}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <CheckBox  x:Name="checkBox"  />
                    <TextBlock  Text="{Binding deviceName}" />
                    <TextBlock  Text="{Binding status}" />
                    <TextBlock  Text="{Binding dateAccessed}" />
                    <TextBlock  Text="{Binding ipAddress}" />
                    <Button Content="Rename Device"  Height="30"/>
                    <Button Content="Remove Device"  Height="30"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

I create a new object of type ObservableCollection and load the values into it from XML file. And then bind the created object to TreeView ItemsSource.

```
public static ObservableCollection<GroupClass> groups = new ObservableCollection<GroupClass>();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("IPProfileData");
XmlSerializer srlzr = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<GroupClass>));
groups = (ObservableCollection<GroupClass>)srlzr.Deserialize(sr);
HostTreeView.ItemsSource = groups;
```

When I click on the Rename Device or Remove Device button, I would like to change the groups Object that is created earlier. Eventually my UI gets changed as TreeView is binded with groups object.

Comment: Do you really need the index of the item or just a reference to the item itself?

Comment: @FlatEric If it's possible to change/delete the selected item in the backend original object ObservableList<GroupClass> through that reference, then the reference works well for me.

Comment: I would add a Command to the ViewModel and bind it in your button: `Command="{Binding DataContext.RenameCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TreeView}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"`

Comment: @FlatEric I am not using MVVM model in my implementation :(

Comment: You can bind to elements in your CodeBehind as well, you just need to set the DataContext, for example: `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}` in your Window or UserControl

Comment: @FlatEric Sorry that I am not able to follow what you are trying to convey, I have edited my question and added the part where I am binding the object that I created to the treeview's Item Source. I believe this might give you more information about the scenario.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190831/discussion-between-sudheer-kumar-and-flat-eric).